# Create a page on wordpress with Python mechanize

Tags: python, wordpress, mechanize

I am trying to create pages on my wordpress site automatically with a Python script. With mechanize, I log in and fill the corresponding form on my dashboard but can't seem to publish. When submitting the form, I get an error page that I can't access manually. Its url is http://example.com/wordpress/wp-admin/post.php?post=443&action=edit&message=10. However, the page seems to have been created since it is in the drafts with the correct title, the correct content and Wordpress tells me that it is currently being modified by my bot's account. Here is the code I am using to fill and submit my form:

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("http://example.com/wordpress/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page")
br.select_form(name = "post")
br.form.set_value(title, name = "post_title")
br.form.set_value(content, name = "content")
br.submit()
```

Thank you for your help,

Ryunos

Comment: With this package you can take it easier. http://python-wordpress-xmlrpc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Thank you, I am now using this package and it works fine!